# Convert image binary data to alphanumeric data without increasing the size

Tags: php, image-processing, optimization, binary-data

I'm new to this. For some reason, I need to convert an image file into some sort of alphanumeric data without increasing much of its file size. I know when you convert binary to hexadecimal, the size will increase. But is there any other way?

Below is something of what I've been doing. I also use gzencode and gzcompress but the size is still significantly larger than its original size.

```
    //Pull the data from your file into a variable. Using the 'rb' tag tells it to read as binary.
    $data = fopen($photo_file_path, 'rb');

    $size = filesize($photo_file_path);

    $contents = fread($data, $size);

    fclose ($data);

    $bintohex = bin2hex($contents);
```

Comment: Binairy data is usually quite compact, so when you set yourself the task of storing less information per byte, the file size will inevitably inflate. It is for instance known that using [base64_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) will inflate the size by roughly 30%. You cannot store the same amount of information, in the same amount of bytes, if the information density is lower.

Comment: You are converting the data to hexadecimal representation in a human readable form. Of course you're increasing the file size significantly. This is just the nature of human-readable. You go from 8 bits per byte to 4 bits per byte, your file size will double.

Comment: There's a reason why all the images on the Internet are encoded as binary JPEGs, PNGs and GIFs  That's the most efficient/compact format.

Comment: Images are already compressed, gzipping will have no effect. What you want is impossible. Base64 is the best you can do (will increase file size 33%).